How to initiate login to OIDC app from Okta using Auth.js
I have an app with Okta auth configured–if I go to my app and I'm not logged in, it'll give me the option to log in via Okta and that's all good.
However, I'd like users to have the ability to initiate the login from Okta itself. Okta has an option for this (adding "Okta" to "Login initiated by" and configuring the "Initiate login URI").
How do I implement this using Next Auth?

[Courtesy of this post]
